# While infinite?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to write a program where you can enter a number and then what number you want it multiplied by and also how many times. After this, you can choose which # step you want and what number it was at that step:

```
numbr= int(raw_input("pick a number: "))
mult= int(raw_input("keep multiplying by what: "))
listy= []
ff= 1

while x < 999999999999999999999999999: 
    numbr *= mult
    listy.append(x)
    ff += 1

cc = int(raw_input("what number do you want: "))
print listy[cc-2]
```

Currently it only goes up to that big number. How can I make it output whatever # step the user wants? If I do while x > 1, then it just loads and doesn't even allow the user to enter what they want. What can I do?

Comment: Your code is completely broken, but either way, could you clarify what you want, exactly? Do you want `numbr` multiplied by `mult`, `cc` times, or...?

Comment: What do you mean by broken? I want 'numbr' multiplied by 'mult' and then when they pick their 'cc' it goes to what # is on that step... For example: numbr=2, mult=2, cc=4 would equal out to 16. Because 2,4,8,16,32,64 and the 4th one (cc) is 16.

Comment: In real world programming, you'll face numerical limits. Using astronomically large integer values will usually require you to use some special, large integer libraries. Also, computers do not have unlimited memory so you can't store unlimited amounts of calculations in an array...

Answer (score 1):

First off, computer memory is limited, and you typically should avoid using more of it than you absolutely need. With the problem in question particularly, you do not need the intermediate values at all - why make a list if you only need a single number?

Also, some random comments on style: Try to make variables self-explanatory, and avoid skipping letters or shortening things when necessary. Anyway, an example of how this could be done:

```
number= int(raw_input("pick a number: "))
multiplier = int(raw_input("keep multiplying by what: "))
times = int(raw_input("multiply how many times: "))

x = 0
while x < times:
    number *= multiplier
    x += 1

print(number)
```

One thing though, you don't have to use a while loop for this, since `for _ in range(times)` does the job just as well, and is additionally more readable. The `_` here is a variable name usually used for values we don't need, e.g. a "discard" variable, and thus the code becomes:

```
number= int(raw_input("pick a number: "))
multiplier = int(raw_input("keep multiplying by what: "))
times = int(raw_input("multiply how many times: "))

for _ in range(times):
    number *= multiplier

print(number)
```

Additionally, if you observe what kind of math you are doing, it is possible to further reduce the code's complexity, since you are effectively multiplying a number by the power of another number, e.g. `numbr * mult^cc` in your original code. Since the operator for power is `**` in Python, the final code is:

```
number= int(raw_input("pick a number: "))
multiplier = int(raw_input("keep multiplying by what: "))
times = int(raw_input("multiply how many times: "))
print(number * multiplier ** times)
```

The code I posted differs from yours a bit, since it doesn't count the original number as a part of our sequence, but well, I'll leave that as an exercise to you, as it is not a very hard one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you multiply a number you are appending it to the list. Your list is keeping track of all 999999999999999999999999999 entries. As the entries get bigger which they do very quickly each one will take up more space in memory. A regular int will start at 8 bits.

You should have the program take whatever step the user wants and calculate it using a formula instead of generating all values up to that point. I think the formula would be: number * mult^cc.